# Build package everytime a file on the workspace is modified?

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I modified some parameters on a file in the catkin worskpace, but nothing happens in the robot. Do i have to build the package everytime i modify something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230341/build-package-everytime-a-file-on-the-workspace-is-modified?/) by [Sed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26422/sed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-03-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-03-28**:
What kind of file is it? Is it copied to the install-directory when building? How do you read the parameter file?

**Comment by [Sed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26422/sed/) on 2016-03-29**:
it is a publisher node in the catkin workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you require the changes in the publisher node to be reflected when you run it, you need to run `catkin_make` after making changes to the source file.

---

Originally posted by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) with karma: 178 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sed](https://answers.ros.org/users/26422/sed/) on 2016-08-04**:
Thank you very much

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-08-04**:
If this solved your problem, could you please mark it answered. Thank You.